# How to send postman GET request using file url

Tags: postman, file-uri

I am trying to send a GET request through [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) using [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). An example:

`file:///absolute/path/to/file.txt`

The request works properly in any browser, but `postman` is failing with message:

> **Could not get any response**
>
> This seems to be like an error connecting to `file:///absolute/path/to/file.txt`

Is there any way to make `postman` work with file URIs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postman does not support file URIs, because the Chrome App platform does not allow direct access to files.

It should be easy to start a small HTTP server yourself though.. if you are on Mac/Linux, you can serve files in a directory using Python:

```
$ cd /path/to/directory/
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234
```

You can then visit

```
http://localhost:1234/filename
```

which will serve up the file.

Answer (score 1):

[Good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716666).

I am not acquainted with *SimpleHTTPServer*, so I used *live-server* instead.

1. I followed the instructions at [2. Install and Run a Local Web Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533794) to install *live-server*.
2. Then:

```
    cd /path/to/(myJSONfile.json)
    live-server <myJSONfile.json>
```

and the JSON file was opened in my default web browser.

3. Finally, in Postman I made a normal **GET** request, but on the address
     `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

It all worked just as intended.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [czardoz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716666/4793216), for Python 3, SimpleHttpServer has been replaced by **http.server**. So, to serve the files using Python 3.x:

```
$ cd/path-to-directory/
$ python -m http.server 1234
```

Then, browse the file using:

```
http://localhost:1234/filename
```